# What kind of SQL injection is this?

Tags: security, sql-injection, code-injection

I've found that someone is trying to attack our company's website via password restore form.
The attack is either a SQL or code injection. It looks like this:

```
'; if (db_name()))<48) waitfor delay \\\'00:00:04\\\'--'
```

there are several variations of the statement above, e.g.

```
'; if (Len((db_name()))=62) waitfor delay \\\'00:00:04\\\'--'
'; if (system_user))<48) waitfor delay \\\'00:00:04\\\'--'
'; if (Len((system_user))=63) waitfor delay \\\'00:00:04\\\'--'
```

Couldn't google anything related to this attack.

Hopefully, somebody know what kind of attack this is and what the attacker is trying to do here?

Comment: http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Time-delay-SQL-injections

Comment: They are attempting to pause your site testing certain scripts to see which one pauses your database, also they are testing if the connection to your site uses which kind of database user. Also checking if your database name is the same length

Comment: I thought of Oracle DB. I will find how this statement can affect both Oracle DB and MS SQL

Comment: SSpoke, so this is a code-injection, not sql?

Comment: It's definitely SQL injection.

Comment: This is SQL injection (t-sql)

Comment: Kenny Thompson, whoa! My google-fu could be better, thank you for the link

Comment: Yes, but SQL injections and code injections are different kinds of injections. SQL injections aim database then code injections trying to modify business logic of your application in a way that an attacker can access FS, read files, modify application settings etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a time-based SQL injection attack.

The attacker knows whether the query is true or not by how fast the page loads with `waitfor delay`. If true then there will be a 4 second delay.

Next the attacker could use substring to slowly extract data from any column in your database that the current database user has permissions to.

example:

*first* character = **a**?

```
 if(ASCII(SUBSTRING((SELECT password FROM admin), 1, 1))=97) waitfor delay ...
```

*second* character = **b**?

```
if(ASCII(SUBSTRING((SELECT password FROM admin), 1, 2))=98) waitfor delay ...
```

if the first letter of column password is 'a' (`ASCII('a') === 97`), the page will delay. By iterating over each character using substring, they could slowly extract your data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are trying to find out information about your DB.

I found information about this type of attack on this site:
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/feature/Time-delay-SQL-injections